# Coger parte del string specifica

Tags: c, string

Tengo un ejercicio en el que tengo una cadena, de la cadena quiero saber por ejemplo: Lo que hay guardado en la cadena en el espacio numero 1 y luego cambiarlo si hiciera falta, hay algún tipo de comando o algo que pueda utilizar para realizar esa orden?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Para acceder a un miembro de la cadena utilizas el operador [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, Sabemos que una string es un conjunto de caracteres.

H = Caracter

Hola = String

Para definir una string en C se hace lo siguiente:

```
char saludo[6];
```

Entendemos que variable *saludo* se almacenaran 6 caracteres. Contando desde 0 en adelante.

```
// 1 2 3 4 5 6 No es asi.

// 0 1 2 3 4 5 Es asi
```

Bien, Ahora vamos a lo que vos queres.

Para saber lo que hay guardado en el espacio 1 de la cadena es tan simple como hacer:

```
printf("%c",cadena[1]);
```

Si queres cambiarle el valor a esto, tenes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
cadena[1]='a'; //A el espacio 1 de la cadena se le asigna el caracter **a**
```

Nota: Es muy importante que los caracteres los guardes simplemente con ' '.

Suerte!